# how to set a shape as a background for a Grid cell

Tags: wpf, grid, styles

iv'e got a grid with 2 rows and 12 columns .
i need to incorporate a style which will draw a triangle for in each cell 
total of 24 cells

the geometry for the triangle for the example :

```
    M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z
```

how could i design and use a style for with this shape in the background each cell in the Grid?

the rows height is approximately 250 and 
column width is approximately  50

[image]

alternatively , each cell contains a stackpanel
so a different solution would be to draw it as the background of a stackpanel how could i draw the shape as the background of the stackpanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a style template for your requirements and apply it to the DataGrid. So basically all you do is add your shape to the template for the DefaultDataGridCellStyle. There's a couple ways of doing this I know of but it's much easier with Expression Blend. Just right-click your datagrid in Blend, choose "Edit Additional Templates" -> Find the GridCell template and "Edit A Copy", you can have it done minutes. Hope this helps!

Example using your path data for the triangle and the height/width set to your specs.

The style template (based off default gridcell template);

```
    <Style x:Key="NewDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Height="250" Width="50">
                <Path Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" Width="Auto"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The ref;

```
<DataGridCell Content="DataGridCell" Style="{DynamicResource NewDataGridCellStyle}"/>
```

Or if you literally meant just a cell to a default regular Grid;

```
    <Grid Width="150" Height="500">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Path Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" />
            <Path Grid.Row="1" Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" />
            <Path Grid.Column="1" Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" />
            <Path Grid.Column="2" Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" />
            <Path Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" />
            <Path Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Data=" M 0, 0 L 25, 250 L 50, 0 z" Fill="#FF39D203" Stroke="#FF2B9F02" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: well i really don't know how to use blend 
i understand that i need ti create a template 
but i don't understand what property i need to use of the stackpanel
because background is for color .
alternatively how could i reference a grid cell in the markup

Comment: How exactly do you want the triangle to appear in your grid cell? I can make you an example and show you how to reference it.

Comment: i'd appreciate that i provided the geometry for the shape in the question above it's suppose to fill the entire height of the row for 
,each cell and the width of each cell 
each cell would border a triangle ( the triangle would be the background)

Comment: o'k i edited the question to be a more precise explanation of what
i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks 
when you say datagridcell how could it be applied to a wpf gridcell
is it the same thing ?
i men't the grid panel cell

Comment: If you meant just a cell of a regular grid look at the added xaml. You could add the additional columns to get the same effect. Hope this helps?

Comment: yeah that second part did the trick for me,
thanks allot , you've been most helpful